# Using points2one plugin in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, polyline-creation, points-to-line, points2one

I downloaded the points2one plugin and tried many times to connect points to a line, but it never worked.

Is there something that I set wrong?

[image]

[image]

I tried the answer, but it has been running for 10 minutes, and does nothing, so should I wait for it?

Comment: hi Taras,I want to connect this 5 point and become a line

Comment: I think maybe I got wrong plugin

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way to achieve your result might be:

1. SAGA's ["Convert Points to Line(s)"](https://saga-gis.sourceforge.io/saga_tool_doc/2.3.0/shapes_lines_1.html) function
2. GRASS's [`v.build.polylines`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass83/manuals/v.build.polylines.html) (available through QGIS itself)
3. points to path (which can be accessed from the Processing > Toolbox (just type in there)